# Whats the best way to animate images to my apporach?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have used

```
image.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4"], nil];


[image setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
image.animationDuration = 1;
[image startAnimating];
```

but it gives a flip book effect to the animation. What I am looking for is a smooth animation to set each image at given time. I have currently is NSTimers to trigger a method then I have code within the method to set a image and another NSTimer to set another image which is in a method so fourth. It gives the animation I am looking for but the problem I am facing is that I am developing a game and I want when the user pauses the game it stops on the current image it is on. The game runs on a NSTimer which triggers a method. All I do to pause the game is to invalidate the NSTimer.

What approach should I take?

Answer (score 0):

you should add NSTimer and user_flag input.
This user_flag input you can declare as `static int user_flag = 0`
and when you are doing stop then simply make this variable as `user_flag = 1`.

Now implement the logic in all this condition that will look something like this one :

```
if(NSTimer_obj == condition && user_flag == 0)
{
       //your code...

}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example im a bit confused @Sandeep Jangir

Comment: my code   movement = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(method) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; - (void) method { movement = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(method2) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]; // image..{ - (void) method2 { // image2... { @Sandeep Jangir